# Meteor\Ionic3 - cannot read property 'versions' of undefined after installing meteor-client-bundler

Tags: meteor, ionic3

I'm doing this [tutorial](https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/meteor-server-side), which combines the Ionic CLI with Meteor. Everything was fine until it asked me to install `meteor-client-bundler`. After adding this to `package.json`:

```
"meteor-client:bundle": "meteor-client bundle -s api"
```

And running the commands:

```
npm install --save-dev tmp
npm run meteor-client:bundle
```

A new file called `meteor-client.js` was added to my `node_modules` folder (as expected). However, when I try importing it via:

```
import 'meteor-client';
```

My app crashes and I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'versions' of undefined
    at autoupdate_client.js (meteor-client.js:40130)
    at fileEvaluate (meteor-client.js:1535)
    at Module.require (meteor-client.js:1438)
    at _require (meteor-client.js:1457)
    at meteor-client.js:40302
    at Object.<anonymous> (meteor-client.js:40308)
    at Object.module.exports (vendor.js:146981)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 38e1b6bf8728472217f2:54)
    at Object.478 (main.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 38e1b6bf8728472217f2:54)
```

The problem appears to be in this line of code:

```
const autoupdateVersions = __meteor_runtime_config__.autoupdate.versions[clientArch] || {
  version: "unknown",
  versionRefreshable: "unknown",
  versionNonRefreshable: "unknown",
  assets: []
};
```

Where apperently versions is undefined. But the code is extremely long and convoluted, I'm not entirely sure how to go about this.